# Override CSS class to remove padding

Tags: html, css, overriding

I am not that familiar with CSS and have a very basic question. I simply want to remove right and left padding from the following "div":

```
<div id="__grid2" data-sap-ui="__grid2" class="noPaddingRightLeft sapUiRespGrid sapUiRespGridHSpace1 sapUiRespGridMedia-Std-LargeDesktop sapUiRespGridVSpace1">
```

"sapUixxx" classes are provided by a framework and cannot be adjusted directly. Therefore I declared a new css class "noPaddingRightLeft" and added it to the div:

```
.sapUiRespGridHSpace1 .noPaddingRightLeft{
padding: 0 0; }
```

When I check the result in the Chrome debugger tools it looks like this:

[CSS at Runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mXWL.png)

There is no sign of my class "noPaddingRightLeft" though it's in the class list of the  element. How can I override sapUixxx css files correctly?

Thanks for help

Tobias

Comment: Just remove the space between the class names: `.sapUiRespGridHSpace1.noPaddingRightLeft {padding: 0; }` this tells the browser it's a single element with both of these classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the important flag to your css

```
.class {
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: This actually works. How dangerous is it to use "!important"? Can this have any side effects? I guess not since my css class "noPaddingRightLeft" is only assigned to one particular "div". Right?

Comment: If you use this only for this class element there will be no effect on the side.

Comment: This will also remove top and bottom padding when the OP only asked for left and right padding to be removed

Comment: Your edited answer is now wrong. you are now only setting top and bottom padding instead of only left and right

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
<div id="__grid2" data-sap-ui="__grid2" class="noPaddingRightLeft sapUiRespGrid sapUiRespGridHSpace1 sapUiRespGridMedia-Std-LargeDesktop sapUiRespGridVSpace1" style = "padding: 0">
```

Or create the css class as following:

```
 #__grid2{
   padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I forgot to mention that my whole HTML tree and even the id are generated at runtime (by a javascript framework). Therefore I simply don't know the ID of this "div" at design time

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
   .sapUiRespGrid.sapUiRespGridHSpace1 {
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly this would apply to all grids that make use of this style class.. I have multiple grids in my application and just want to apply this to one specific div.

Comment: You should add class or ID to your DIV and target it like this: 
`#yourDIV .sapUiRespGrid.sapUiRespGridHSpace1 { padding: 0; }`